# App automatically comes to foreground upon starting an activity

Tags: android, service, background, foreground

I have a service which based on a certain scenario finishes(calls finish() method) on one activity, say Activity A and launches another activity B. All works fine except for when the user puts the app in the background by clicking on the home button. In the meantime, my service is getting called and it launches the activity B by calling startActivity() and hence my app which was in background is automatically coming to the foreground. How do i stop this. I need my activity B to be launched when the service is invoked but i do not want my app to automatically come to the foreground.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that's impossible to do. You cannot launch an activity without making it visible. That is the point of an Activity, to offer an interface to your user

Comment: Before launching the activity, check whether your service is running or not.

Comment: Actually in Xiomi devices the app doesn't force open itself when the activity...the new activity launches when the user returns to the app. So i know that this is possible. Just don't know how. I am stuck!